# getLoginStatusUrl() Not Working For Me

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

forgive me for the stupid question. I am trying to use the getLoginStatusUrl function in the PHP SDK, but I'm not sure I'm understanding what it is supposed to do correctly. I made the function call like they said:

```
$params = array(
'ok_session' => 'myapp.com/',
'no_user' => 'myapp.com/no_user',
'no_session' => 'myapp.com/no_session',
);

$next_url = $facebook->getLoginStatusUrl($params);
```

And examine the $next_url in my error log with:

```
error_log((string)$next_url);
```

Which shows up like:

http://www.facebook.com/exter/login_status.php?api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX0&no_session=http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.com&no_user=http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.com&ok_session=http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.com&session_version=3

However, this doesn't really tell me what I want to know, which is whether or not the user is logged in. I am aware that there is another way to check for whether or not a user is supposedly logged in, but that method is not working for me. Sometimes, it returns the user's user ID when they are not actually logged in (when it should supposedly be returning null). Thus, I wanted to use this function, getLoginStatusUrl as a backup in case if that failed.

Could somebody please help me solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

`getLoginStatusUrl()` will return a URL based on the user’s login status on Facebook. In your case if the user is logged in then `myapp.com/` page will be shown, if the user is logged out of Facebook then `myapp.com/no_user` page will be shown, if user is not connected(including not a facebook user) then `myapp.com/no_session` page will be shown. Therefore you will know whether a user is logged in or not, by the page which is displayed. 
 The function just redirects to the specified url(Listed in `$params`) according to user's current facebook status.